# Deferred setAttribute call in Custom Element constructor causes DOM error. Is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

Here's a fiddle showing an error in console in Chrome 72 and Firefox 63:

https://jsfiddle.net/jr2z1ms3/1/

The code is:

```html
    <script>
    customElements.define('test-element', class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
       super()
       Promise.resolve().then(() => {
         this.setAttribute('foo', 'bar')
        })
      }
    })
    </script>
    <test-element>test</test-element>
```

In Chrome the error is:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have attributes
```

In Firefox the error is:

```
NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported
```

If you comment the `setAttribute` call, the error goes away in both browsers.

The following example illustrates changing attributes before an element is connected, which shows that it can be done with macrotasks, yet (unfairly) not with microtasks:

([working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thx4mzvk/) for snippet below)

```js
    customElements.define('test-element', class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super()
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setAttribute('foo', 'bar')
        })
      }
      
      connectedCallback() {
       console.log('foo attribute:', this.getAttribute('foo'))
      }
    })
    
    const el = document.createElement('test-element')
    
    console.log('no foo attribute:', el.getAttribute('foo'))
    
    setTimeout(() => {
     document.body.appendChild(el)
    })
```

In the first example I am not setting the attribute in the constructor, I am deferring to a future microtask. So why are the browsers complaining? If this is intended as per spec, then does the spec have a "design bug"? Why should we not be able to do this?

based on answers below, I don't see why this limitation ***needs*** to be in place. A bad developer can still make a mess with or without this browser-engine limitation in place.

IMO, let devs decide (and document) how their custom elements work.

Is there some technical limitation that the browser otherwise can't overcome if we were to be able to set attributes in the contructor or a microtask after the constructor?

Comment: When does your Promise resolve? So is your Element in the DOM? Add some console logs and a connectedCallback

Comment: It may be in the DOM when constructed (i.e. during parsing), or not (i.e. during `document.createElement()` or `new Ctor`). I guess the issue is that I don't really see what harm can come of it. Do you know any specific examples of scenarios that could be bad if I were to set an attribute in a microtask from the constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance) there are certain things you must never do in the constructor:

> When authoring custom element constructors, authors are bound by the following conformance requirements:
>
> - A parameter-less call to super() must be the first statement in the constructor body, to establish the correct prototype chain and this value before any further code is run.
> - A return statement must not appear anywhere inside the constructor body, unless it is a simple early-return (return or return this).
> - The constructor must not use the document.write() or document.open() methods.
> - **The element's attributes and children must not be inspected**, as in the non-upgrade case none will be present, and relying on upgrades makes the element less usable.
> - **The element must not gain any attributes or children**, as this violates the expectations of consumers who use the createElement or createElementNS methods.
> - In general, work should be deferred to connectedCallback as much as possible—especially work involving fetching resources or rendering. However, note that connectedCallback can be called more than once, so any initialization work that is truly one-time will need a guard to prevent it from running twice.
> - In general, the constructor should be used to set up initial state and default values, and to set up event listeners and possibly a shadow root.
>
> Several of these requirements are checked during element creation, either directly or indirectly, and failing to follow them will result in a custom element that cannot be instantiated by the parser or DOM APIs.

The problem with your example is that the `Promise` is resolved immediately and is, thus, still in the constructor.

If you change your code to this:

```js
customElements.define('test-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setAttribute('foo', 'bar')
    }, 100)
  }
})
```

```html
<test-element>test</test-element>
```

Then it works because the `setTimeout` gets you out of the constructor.

Comment: Right, I get that, but I don't understand why microtasks are not allowed while macrotasks are, as the result is practically the same: the attributes will be set after the user's synchronous DOM manipulation code either way, except in the case of parsing. What harm could come out of setting attributes in a microtask? maybe that's the better question.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the size of the task. A component can be created using `new` or `document.createElement` or through `innerHTML`. The component is created before any children or attributes are added/changed. All of these things happen after the `new` element is created. With that the rules for not changing children or attributes become clearer. First the element is created, then attributes are set/children are added. If you try to manipulate attributes or children in your constructor then you are going against the lifespan functionality of how an element is created.

Comment: Yeah, but like I said, I can defeat the mechanism by using `setTimeout` to fire a macrotask, so I don't see why microtasks get different treatment. I can inherently do it the "wrong way" with a macrotask, so why prevent it only for microtasks?

Comment: You must exit the constructor before attempting to read or change any attributes or children. `Promise.resolve` does not do that. Calling `setTimeout` allows the constructor to finish before calling the handler of `setTimeout`. Anything that allows the constructor to exit is sufficient.

Comment: Think of it this way, Custom Elements are like houses, during the ``constructor`` phase the house does **not** have an address. So you can't call IKEA and have (*anything that decorates*) delivered... or order pizza from Dominos.. or call Lyft..... In the ``connectedCallback`` your Element has an address (it is in the DOM) and you can do/order anything you want. Your setTimeout **just waits**... meanwhile the builders have finished your house and it got an address. So.... your `microtask` is **NOT** EXECUTING in the ``constructor`` phase

Comment: @Intervalia Yes, `Promise.resolve().then()` does defer the code beyond the completion of the constructor, to the JavaScript engine's following microtask, allowing the constructor to exit before the code in the `then` handler fires.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman "your microtask is NOT EXECUTING in the constructor phase" I know! It happens after the constructor exits. I updated the question to show an example with `setTimeout`, showing an attribute is set before the element is connected. I don't see what harm there would be in allowing it to be possible with microtasks. A bad dev can still make a mess with out without this browser engine safe guard in place, and I don't see the benefit of it yet.

Comment: It is no safeguard, It is JavaScript & DOM 101.. **you can't set something if it is not there yet**. Are you coming from React??? Remember React Virtual DOM (built everything in JavaScript **memory**) is **NOT** the document DOM. In another analogy... you want to buy a dress for your kid before you even conceived a child... (yes.. wrong analogy... its 22:00 here in Amsterdam.. I already had 2 *screwdrivers*)

Answer (score 1):

The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance) mentions this:

> This is true even if the work is done inside a constructor-initiated microtask, as a microtask checkpoint can occur immediately after construction.

Comment: I guess a better question is "why?". Why should we not be allowed to do this, specifically? We can do it with a macrotask (f.e. Intervalia's answer), which for all intents and purposes is almost the same.

Comment: The constructor is just that: It ONLY CONSTRUCTS the basic object. After that, in different microtasks, the browser parses attributes, appends this object into a DOM and parses child elements. Then the browser calls the appropriate methods on this object to set those attribute values and append those children.